# How do we disable pop up calendar on required date field in event registration?

Tags: dates, calendar, datepicker

About 25% (?) of our event registrants are screwing up the year portion of pop-up calendar. We see no way to disable the pop-up calendar graphic on date fields regardless of date format (yyyy-mm-dd) but it's a pretty major headache.

Advice?

Comment: Can you please give more details? How are they screwing it up? What's different about your date format?

Comment: Users will generally just click on it forcing today and move on, so they're a day old, or will select their month/day but leave year alone, so they're a few months old.

Comment: I couldn't fully understand your question, but as far as I can grasp, I will try to provide an answer. If having the Year information at the beginning in the date format is causing issues while creating an event, you can set the desired date format by going to "Settings" > "Placement" > "Date Format" and selecting an appropriate preset.

Comment: Thank you for the response. We are attempting to remove/disable the calendar pop-up widget ENTIRELY and have user just enter number YYYY-MM-DD. We are finding no native, configurable means to do so and are exploring a CSS hide... but it's not going well yet.